# Changing a One To Many, to a Many to Many relationship?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a one to many relationship (client has many actions) which i'd like to change to a many to many relationship (person has many actions and actions belongs to many persons).

What are the best steps of action?

I've created the pivot table persons_actions and added changes to the models.

Person model

```
    public function actions()
    {
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\Action', 'person_actions', 'person_id', 'action_id')
                ->withTimestamps();
    }
```

Actions model

```
    public function persons()
    {
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\Person', 'person_actions')
                ->withTimestamps();
    }
```

and have been looking for some time on the next steps to take on converting the actions over to the person_actions table.

On the Client there is a "main_person_id" column, which I'd like all of the current actions to be assigned to when moving to the Person model.

Comment: What was the old relation ship? Person has many actions? With respect to main_person_id, thats a separate relationship from the relationship of person to action. Once you have your many to many setup up you can do $client->main_person->actions.

Comment: If you need something fancy like $client->main_actions, then you can use a hasManyThrough relationship I believe.